# SQL Выборка по уникальному полю и группировка

Tags: mysql, sql, выборка

Подскажите по выборке повторяющихся значений.
Есть таблица

```
 ( 1,   'user1',    'Новое сообщение',  '2014-02-15' ),
 ( 2,   'user2',    'Новое сообщение',  '2015-05-07' ),
 ( 3,   'user3',    'Новое сообщение',  '2015-09-12' ),
 ( 4,   'user2',    'Регистрация',      '2016-05-16' ),
 ( 5,   'user1',    'Новое сообщение',  '2016-05-16' ),
 ( 6,   'user4',    'Создание темы',    '2016-05-12' )
```

Как написать запрос, что бы получить сколько юзеров  в каждом году написали сообщения **впервые**,т.е. должно на выходе быть

```
2014   1
2015   2
2016   0
```

Если написать данный код

```
SELECT  
  Extract(YEAR from Date) As Year,
  Count(DISTINCT user) AS Count
FROM table 
WHERE
  Type LIKE 'Новое%'
GROUP BY
  Extract(YEAR from Date)
```

то на выходе будет

```
Year    Count
2014    1
2015    2
2016    1
```

И я, собственно, понимаю почему так происходит. Как решить данную задачу ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

Сначала отобрать минимальный номер года, в котором у пользователя появилось новое сообщение, а потом из всего этого сделать группировку с суммированием по годам:

```
select
  Year,
  count(user) as Count
from 
  (
    select
      min(extract(YEAR from Date)) as Year,
      user as User
    from table
    where
      Type like 'Новое%'
    group by
      user
  ) as FirstMessageYears
group by
  Year
```

Уникальность обеспечивается тем, что мы можем получить только одну минимальную дату для каждого пользователя, так что `distinct` не понадобится.

Для дополнения строками с годами, по которым есть сообщения, но не первые, можно воспользоваться тем, что count(null) возвращает 0:

Внутренний запрос усложнился тем, что теперь он возвращает года, для которых нет пользователя с первым сообщением, со значение null в колонке пользователя.

```
select
  AllYears.Year,
  count(FirstMessageYears.User) as Count
from 
  (
    select
      min(extract(YEAR from Date)) as Year,
      user as User
    from table
    where
      Type like 'Новое%'
    group by
      user
  ) as FirstMessageYears right join 
    (
      select distinct
        extract(YEAR from Date) as Year
      from table
    ) as AllYears on 
    FirstMessageYears.Year = AllYears.Year
group by
  AllYears.Year
```

---

Давайте попробуем разобраться. Начинаем "выполнять" SQL запрос "изнутри", т.е. с тех частей, что находятся на максимальном уровне вложенности. В нашем случае, вложенным является сложный подзапрос:

```
  (
    select
      min(extract(YEAR from Date)) as Year,
      user as User
    from table
    where
      Type like 'Новое%'
    group by
      user
  ) as FirstMessageYears right join 
    (
      select distinct
        extract(YEAR from Date) as Year
      from table
    ) as AllYears on 
    FirstMessageYears.Year = AllYears.Year
```

---

Чтобы понять, что этот подзапрос возвращает, давайте разбирать его на запчасти:

```
  (
    select
      min(extract(YEAR from Date)) as Year,
      user as User
    from table
    where
      Type like 'Новое%'
    group by
      user
  ) as FirstMessageYears
```

**right join**

```
    (
      select distinct
        extract(YEAR from Date) as Year
      from table
    ) as AllYears
```

---

Вот, уже немножно легче. Имеем два запроса, каждый возвращает таблицу, потом эти таблицы **объединяются** посредством операции с непонятным названием `right join`.

Сначала разберёмся, что возвращают каждая из частей перед объединением.

Первый результат подзапроса с красноречивым названием `FirstMessageYears` будет содержать две колонки: `пользователь` + `дата первого сообщения`.

Второй результат подзапроса с названием `AllYears` будет содержать одну колонку, в которой будут перечислены все года, встречающиеся в исходной таблице `table`.

Что будет, если применить к этим двум наборам операцию `right join`? Получится таблица, состоящая из двух столбцов, `номер года` и `пользователь`. Логически, этот набор заполняется в 2 этапа:

Сначала, в результат объединения попадают те строчки из набора `AllYears`, для которых нет соответствия в наборе `FirstMessageYears`. Поле `пользователь` для этих строчек остаётся `null`.

Потом, в результат объединения попадают те строчки из набора `FirstMessageYears`, для которых есть соответствие в наборе `AllYears`. Поле `пользователь` для этих строчек берётся из набора `FirstMessageYears`.

---

Остаётся провести по этому результирующему колдовству группировку:

```
select
  AllYears.Year,
  count(FirstMessageYears.User) as Count
from 
  [результат выполнения подзапроса]
group by
  Year
```

а мы помним, что колонка `FirstMessageYears.User` оказалась со значеним `null` в тех строчках, которые соответствуют годам, в которые не было первого сообщения от кого-либо из пользователей. Count(null) возвращает 0. Ву-а-ля.

Comment: Мне понравился ваш подход, но вывод получается без 2016 года. Как сделать, что бы так же выводил года, где 0 user'ов ?

Comment: @ka6an4eg Ну раз получается, то принимайте ответ

Comment: случайно энтер нажал, не дописав ) прочитайте заново коммент, отредактировал

Comment: @ka6an4eg пробуйте

Comment: Супер! Теперь осталось разобраться как это работает:) Спасибо! Может посоветуете что нибудь почитать, что бы разобраться?

Comment: И может, если не затруднит еще своими словами в кратце. Буду очень признателен

Comment: Начинайте отсюда: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: @ka6an4eg Я попробовал объяснить, не судите строго.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я в принципе так же и разбирал по кускам только что, но вдруг где не так понял логику.Теперь все точно встало на свои места в моей голове :)